# My PushMenu mask is not acting the same after first click and I cant seem to see the issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After I run this code for the first time, the mask fades in neatly. But when its close and thus deleted then reclicked without refreshing, the mask doesnt fade in just pops out and slides disgustingly. Heres the whole file combined:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pumpkin-Box</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<img style="position:absolute; top:60px; left:425px" src="Pumpkin5.jpg">

<div class='hol'>
<link href="Pumpkin Box.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="close">
        <img src="close.png"/>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Help</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="icon-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
      var mask = document.createElement('div');
        mask.className="mask";

      var main = function(){
         $('.icon-menu').click(function(){
             document.body.appendChild(mask);
             $('.mask').animate({
                left:'285px'
             },350);




             $('.menu').animate({
                 left:'0px'
                 },350);

             $('#wrapper').animate({
                marginLeft:'290px'
                },350);

             $('.mask').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);

             $('.mask').click(function(){

                    $('.mask').animate({
                        left:'0'
                    },350);

                    $('.mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.0);

                    $('.mask').remove();
                    $('.menu').animate({
                        left:'-290px'
                    },350);



                    $('#wrapper').animate({
                        marginLeft:'0px'
                    },350);

                    });

         });

             $('.close').click(function(){

                 $('.mask').animate({
                left:'0'
                },350);

                $('.mask').remove();

                $('.menu').animate({
                    left:'-290px'
                },350);

                $('#wrapper').animate({
                    marginLeft:'0px'
                },350);



             });


      };

    $(document).ready(main);

</script>
<style>
.mask{
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
 }

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You in advance :D

Comment: there you go i wrote the whole html